# Former 401(k) plan closed and check mailed to me. Can I roll over this money and avoid paying tax?

Tags: united-states, taxes, 401k, ira, rollover

My former employer's 401(k) plan has been terminated and I was mailed a distribution check with 20% tax withheld. However, I wanted to move my money into my current employer's 401(k) and not pay tax. Is there a way to fix this?

One representative I spoke to suggested moving the money into a new IRA, making up the difference from my own pocket, and then asking for a rebate a tax time. Will this work?

Thanks.

Comment: Did they not give enough warning so employees could transfer to IRA with no withholding issues?

Comment: they did, but I forgot to speak with them before the deadline... so this is about fixing a mess I got myself into.

Comment: Make sure you understand what portion is pretax, posttax and earnings.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I assume it's all pretax since it was from an employer 401k? Or do I not understand something?

Comment: You can put money into a 401K before taxes, after taxes, and now they even have a Roth 401K. You may have done everything pretax, but not everybody does it that way.

Comment: mhoran's warning is right. Doesn't apply to most, but important to know if it did, what the impact is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> One representative I spoke to suggested moving the money into a new
>   IRA, making up the difference from my own pocket, and then asking for
>   a rebate a tax time. Will this work?

That's probably the only thing that will work, and you have to do this ASAP: you have 60 days from the distribution to complete the deposit.

Make sure to make up for the withheld 20%, and deposit into the IRA the **full** amount, and make sure to give all the relevant information to your tax preparer to ensure you do get the withheld 20% back as a tax credit.

You can check with your current 401k plan if you can deposit there, but in many cases you cannot. IRA is a safe bet.

Comment: thanks. this is what I've been hearing from other sources as well.

Comment: I was told that unless i redeposited the check I got into the ira that I would be responsible for the taxes.  That I could not deposit it in my account and then put it into the new IRA with out penalties and taxes.

Comment: @Chad I'm not sure if you must redeposit that exact check, I don't think so. It might be that you were told that in a case of a *direct* rollover, then you must indeed deposit the check directly to the IRA account.

Comment: @littleadv ok that is probably why

Comment: BTW--this worked fine, it just sucked that I had to come up with the money to make up the withheld tax. I actually went in to a Schwab branch and met with a teller to make the deposit. You will need all your documentation.